# How query specific date with dbc.tablesV.LastAccessTimeStamp in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I need a help to find how to cast timestamp for this case.
I tried:

```
cast('2017-01-04 13:00:00' as timestamp(0) format'YYYY-MM-DDBHH:MI:SS')
```

The query is as follows:

```
`SELECT
  b.databasename,
  a.tablename,
  a.CreatorName,
  a.CreateTimeStamp,
  a.LastAccessTimeStamp,
  sum(currentperm)/(1024*1024) as tbsize
 FROM dbc.tablesV a
 INNER JOIN dbc.tablesizeV b
 ON a.tablename = b.tablename
 AND a.databasename=b.databasename
 WHERE a.databasename = 'tablea' 
 AND a.LastAccessTimeStamp = '2017-01-14 13:00:00'
 GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;`
```

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

No need for any kind of Cast/Format to specify a timestamp, there's only a single format when you simply put the word `timestamp` in front:

```
TIMESTAMP 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'
TIMESTAMP '2016-08-11 19:17:11'
```

Btw, your 1st approach should work as-is.

Comment: Hi Dnoeth, Thank you very very much for your help.